# How can I use this string in an e-mail filter?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

Apologies for the amount of redaction. Basically the e-mail is `"notify.mydomain.com <support@mydomain.com>"`

I'd like to filter anything which is 'notify.mydomain.com' but I can't work out which field it is in the outlook e-mail filter rules. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the rules wizard - the answer is not really obvious

[image]

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve? What you've tried? How exactly it doesn't work? ...

Comment: I've tried to work out which field it is but it's unclear - I will add a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

[image]

This should work for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

> With specific words in the sender's address

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. The filter is not catching the messages. It's more like the sender's name or something, rather than their address. I'm not sure about what part of the e-mail format is the sender name